# Can two request be mapped to a single stateless EJB instance concurrently

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Can two request be mapped to a single stateless EJB instance concurrently?

Or must the container map the requests to different instances or serialize the requests?

The [EJB 3.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) states:

> This means, for example, that [...] the
>   container may interleave requests from multiple transactions to the same instance.

Which sounds like concurrency would be allowed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to stateful and stateless session beans must be serialized by the container.

This is from Section 4.3.14 of the [EJB 3.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/):

> The container serializes calls to each stateful and stateless session bean instance. Most containers will
>   support many instances of a session bean executing concurrently; however, each instance sees only a
>   serialized sequence of method calls. Therefore, a stateful or stateless session bean does not have to be
>   coded as reentrant.